# how to make navigator bar (responsive) in front of title

Tags: html, navigation, responsive-design

i try to make my blog responsive but my navigator menu is behind the title, i want to make it in front of my title. you can look the print screen here

[print-screen](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/135911164/prtscrn.png)

and here's the nav code on media query;

```
.nav {
max-width:599px;
position: relative;
float:center;
padding-bottom:120px;
top:159px;
left:-60px;
min-height: 40px;
padding-top:0;
} 

.nav ul {
/*width: 599px;*/
padding: 5px 0;
position: absolute;
/*top: -13px;
left: -95px;*/
border: solid 1px #2FB8C8;
background: #2FB8C8 url(../images/icon-menu.png) no-repeat 10px 11px;
}

.nav li {
display: none; /* hide all <li> items */
margin: 0;
opacity:0.8;
}

.nav .current {
display: block; /* show only current <li> item */
}

.nav a {
display: block;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 32px;
text-align: left;
width:599px;
}

.nav .current a {
background: none;
color: #666;
}

/* on nav hover */
.nav ul:hover {
opacity:1;
}

.nav ul:hover li {
display: block;
margin: 0 0 5px;
}

.nav ul:hover .current {
background: url(../images/icon-check.png) no-repeat 10px 7px;
}
```

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could set the z-index explicitly to bring those elements forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav {

z-index:2

max-width:599px;
position: relative;
float:center;
padding-bottom:120px;
top:159px;
left:-60px;
min-height: 40px;
padding-top:0;
} 

.Title{
/*or what ever you gave it*/
z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Did you give the logo a position? Because it wont work if the position is static

Answer (score -1):

Check the following links for your guide. You also need to use jQuery.

```
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/19/responsive-multi-level-menu/
http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/responsive-menu/
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/
```